# Can I submit my paper somewhere else during rebuttal period?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission

During a rebuttal period, with reviews that show a strong indication of overall reject, can I submit the paper to another venue (without violating concurrent submission rules)? The submission deadline in the other venue is before the final response of the current venue.

Comment: The unedited question opened with "If the rebuttal responses show a strong indication of overall reject," which doesn't seem right. I presume the OP mean "reviews" rather than "rebuttal responses," so I edited. @seq: Please revise if you meant something else

Comment: It's a paper from a presentation at a conference intended for the published proceedings? It concerns me the conference might have some proprietary interest in the paper, especially if there was any financial support given to the presentation. It might not even be acceptable to withdraw and then submit elsewhere. Though I am by no means confident of this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I submit my paper somewhere else during rebuttal period?

No: Your paper is under review, submitting elsewhere would be a parallel submission. You could withdraw your paper and then submit elsewhere. Albeit, withdrawal seems unethical at this late stage.

Comment: You may also consider "decline to revise" (if available) prior to notifying the editor of the withdrawal.

Comment: @user3024069 _decline to revise_ surely isn't available during a rebuttal period, since authors are being asked to respond to reviews, so there's nothing to decline. I suppose authors could decline to respond, but the paper remains under review.

Comment: "withdrawal seems unethical at this late stage." Why, though? If they liked to see the paper at the conference, they shouldn't have given it an assessment that is clearly leaning towards rejection.

Comment: After all, the overall review period would probably be shorter if they didn't have a rebuttal phase. In that sense, not allowing that papers with a clearly negative evaluation are withdrawn (by deeming it unethical) feels like "taking the papers hostage".

Comment: Re. "withdrawal seems unethical at this late stage" - withdrawing a submission after negative reviews isn't uncommon, from what I've seen, nor is it considered unethical. Indeed, some conferences (e.g. ICLR) have a formal withdrawal policy (see https://iclr.cc/Conferences/2020/CallForPapers), which suggests it's perfectly normal and not frowned upon. As they say, "Authors have the right to withdraw papers from consideration at any time until paper notification." Many authors have exercised that right this year: https://openreview.net/group?id=ICLR.cc/2020/Conference#withdrawn-submissions

Comment: #Stuart Golodetz of course one can withdraw its own work, but doing so after starting A REBUTTAL does not seem logical neither correct. Rebuttal isn't addressing the referee comment, is refusal of those very comment at first. It is quite a drastic solution which involves the editor time and assessment more than usual. As an editor I would be very disappointed if someone started a rebuttal then withdraw the paper.

Comment: @Alchimista: I think 'rebuttal' may mean different things in our respective contexts. In my field (computer vision), many conferences have a rebuttal period (of usually around a week) once the initial reviews for a paper are released to the authors, during which time the authors are invited to respond to the reviewers ("rebut" their comments). It's quite normal for authors to decide to withdraw their submission after the rebuttal period has started, as a result of receiving negative reviews (indeed, they only see the negative reviews at that point). How does your field work?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to submit elsewhere, the proper course is to formally withdraw your paper. Send a note to the editor. Then you are free to submit elsewhere. Don't make assumptions.